# I can't center align my image border radius with the text

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, division

How to center text with the image having border-radius of 50%, horizontally.

Below is the code:

```
<div>
<img src="images/kristen.png" alt=""  class="box">
<span>Kristen Wu</span>
```

```
.box{
border-radius: 50%;
display: flex;
height: 40px;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[image: Image of how I want it to look like]

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload an image of what the expected outcome should look like?

To center the image within your div tag, you can achieve this by applying:`margin: 0 auto;` in your `.box` class.

This is equivalent to the following:

```
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
```

Basically centering your image horizontally.

Comment: Oops That didn't work.  I mean the text would be just beside the image border radius. I already attached the image in y question. Check it

Comment: There are no images attached.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if my answer is not right, because i catch your mean is to make align center. Maybe it can help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
   width:100px;
   height:75px;
   background-color:red;
   border:1px solid black;
}
#div2
{
   transform:rotate(30deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
   -moz-transform:rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transform:rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
   background-color:yellow;
}
.box{
border-radius: 50%;
display: flex;
height: 40px;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.wrapper{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "wrapper">
<img src="images/kristen.png" alt=""  class="box">
<span>Kristen Wu</span> </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to align something to centre in HTML is the center tag.
You can use that to centre anything. And the code you wrote for border radius is also correct.

PS. center is the right spelling for the code. IF you write centre, it wont work